# Sum of two numbers is $32$ and sum of their squares is $904$. What are the numbers?

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations

According to the problem I've tried

$$x+y=32.........(1)$$

$$x^2+y^2=904........(2)$$

Now, I know $x^2+y^2$ can be written as-
$$(x+y)^2+2xy$$

But don't know how to solve further steps. Please help.

Comment: $-2xy$ not $+2xy$

Comment: Hint: If you know (or can deduce) $x+y=p$ and $xy=q$, then $x$ and $y$ are the zeros of the quadratic (in the variable $T$)
$$(T-x)(T-y)=T^2-pT+q.$$ You can find the zeros with the quadratic formula.

Answer (score 3):

$$y=32-x$$

$$x^2+(32-x)^2=904$$

$$2x^2-64x+32^2-904=0$$

$$2x^2-64x+120=0$$

$$x^2-32x+60=0$$

$$(x-2)(x-30)=0$$

Are you able to solve the remaining?

Answer (score 2):

We can write $x^2+y^2$ as $(x+y)^2-2xy$. We know that $x+y=32$. So, we thus get, $2xy =120 \Rightarrow xy=60$.

---

Now use the fact that $(x-y)^2 = (x+y)^2-4xy$. Solve for $(x-y)$ and thus we can get the answer for $x$ by adding $(x-y)$ and $(x+y)$. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

$x+y=32.........[1]$

$x^2+y^2=904$

$\implies (x+y)^2–2xy=904$

$\implies 2xy=(x+y)^2–904$

$\implies 2xy=32^2–904$

$\implies xy=60$

$(x-y)^2=(x+y)^2–4xy$

$\implies (x-y)^2=32^2–4\times 60$

$\implies x-y=28.......[2]$

[I’m not writing $\pm 28$, since I am considering $x>y$]

Now, solving [1] and [2] simultaneously gives

$2x=60$

$\implies x=30$

$\implies y=2$